# Elasticsearch: strict_dynamic_mapping_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

**Hi,
I am trying to modify the date format in an elasticsearch index (operate-operation-0.26.0_). But I get the following error.**

```json
{
  "took" : 148,
  "errors" : true,
  "items" : [
    {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "operate-operation-0.26.0_",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "WBGhSXcB_hD8-yfn-Rh5",
        "status" : 400,
        "error" : {
          "type" : "strict_dynamic_mapping_exception",
          "reason" : "mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dynamic] within [_doc] is not allowed"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**The json file I am using is bulk6.json:**

```json
{"index":{}}

{"dynamic":"strict","properties":{"date":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"}}}
```

**The command I am running is**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST 'localhost:9200/operate-operation-0.26.0_/_bulk?pretty&refresh' --data-binary @"bulk6.json"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_bulk` API endpoint is not meant for changing mappings. You need to use the [`_mapping` API endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) like this:

The JSON file `mapping.json` should contain:

```json
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
    }
  }
}
```

And then the call can be made like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 'localhost:9200/operate-operation-0.26.0_/_mapping?pretty&refresh' --data-binary @"mapping.json"
```

**However, this is still not going to work** as you're not allowed to change the date format after the index has been created. You're going to get the following error:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapper for [date] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [format] from [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis] to [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Mapper for [date] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [format] from [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis] to [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

You need to create a new index with the desired correct mapping and reindex your data.